# Should I use Unicode string by default?

Tags: python, unicode

Is it considered as a good practice to pick Unicode string over regular string when coding in Python? I mainly work on the Windows platform, where most of the string types are Unicode these days (i.e. .NET String, '_UNICODE' turned on by default on a new c++ project, etc ). Therefore, I tend to think that the case where non-Unicode string objects are used is a sort of rare case.  Anyway, I'm curious about what Python practitioners do in real-world projects.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From my practice -- use unicode.

At beginning of one project we used usuall strings, however our project was growing, we were implementing new features and using new third-party libraries. In that mess with non-unicode/unicode string some functions started failing. We started spending time localizing this problems and fixing them. However, some third-party modules doesn't supported unicode and started failing after we switched to it (but this is rather exclusion than a rule).

Also I have some experience when we needed to rewrite some third party modules(e.g. SendKeys) cause they were not supporting unicode. If it was done in unicode from beginning it will be better :)

So I think today we should use unicode.

P.S. All that mess upwards is only my hamble opinion :)

Comment: +1: always use unicode when you are handling text. Whenever the need arises to treat the text data as bytes (for instance when moving over network or writing to disk) - convert the unicode to a sequence of bytes (represented as a string in Python). Convert by calling encode or unicode.

Answer (score 13):

As you ask this question, I suppose you are using Python 2.x.

Python 3.0 changed quite a lot in string representation, and all text now is unicode.
I would go for unicode in any new project - in a way compatible with the switch to Python 3.0 (see [details](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit)).

Comment: Yeah, future compatibility is quite important!

Answer (score 13):

Yes, use unicode.

Some hints:

1. When doing input output in any sort of binary format, decode directly after reading and encode directly before writing, so that you never need to mix strings and unicode. Because mixing that tends to lead to UnicodeEncodeDecodeErrors sooner or later.
2. [Forget about this one, my explanations just made it even more confusing. It's only an issue when porting to Python 3, you can care about it then.]
3. Common Python newbie errors with Unicode (not saying you are a newbie, but this may be read by newbies): Don't confuse encode and decode. Remember, UTF-8 is an ENcoding, so you ENcode Unicode to UTF-8 and DEcode from it.
4. Do not fall into the temptation of setting the default encoding in Python (by setdefaultencoding in sitecustomize.py or similar) to whatever you use most. That is just going to give you problems if you reinstall or move to another computer or suddenly need to use another encoding. Be explicit.
5. Remember, not all of Python 2s standard library accepts unicode. If you feed a method unicode and it doesn't work, but it should, try feeding it ascii and see. Examples: urllib.urlopen(), which fails with unhelpful errors if you give it a unicode object instead of a string.

Hm. That's all I can think of now!

Comment: Point 3 is so true - everybody I know (including me) made this error, and not only once!

Comment: Re: "encode directly after writing" -- can you clarify?  I think that should be "before" instead of "after", but I might be missing your point.

Comment: @Lennart: "Note that even if you after encode unicode into a string full of non-ascii text, this is still text, according to Python." ... In 3.x, str.encode() returns type bytes, and the ascii or not distinction seems irrelevant; what is the point that you are trying to make?

Comment: @ars: Correct, fixed that. @John: Ehhh, I think I only made things more confusing. It's not an important point, so I removed it.

Comment: @Lennart: What would be the problem of generating UTF-8 output by default? This is much better than programs that do different things on different platforms.  If people don’t like UTF-8, they can pipe stuff through iconv.  The program is more reliable when it does the same thing all the time.  Every program I ever write, whether in Perl, Python, or Java, always forces stdin and stdout to UTF-8 (but accepts overrides from the environment).  I simply can’t stand the way default platform encodings screw you.

Comment: @tchrist: "Setting the default encoding" refers to setting sys.defaultencoding and then using just `.encode()` instead of passing in the encode explicitly. Don't do that. There is absolutely no problem with using UTF-8 as your programs default encoding. Update the question to make the distinction clearer.

Answer (score 6):

It can be tricky to consistently use unicode strings in Python 2.x - be it because somebody inadvertently uses the more natural `str(blah)` where they meant `unicode(blah)`, forgetting the `u` prefix on string literals, third-party module incompatibilities - whatever. So in Python 2.x, use unicode only if you have to, and are prepared to provide good unit test coverage.

If you have the option of using Python 3.x however, you don't need to care - strings will be unicode with no extra effort.

Answer (score 4):

Additional to Mihails comment I would say: Use Unicode, since it is the future. In Python 3.0, Non-Unicode will be gone, and as much I know, all the "U"-Prefixes will make trouble, since they are also gone.

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with severely constrained memory or disk space, use ASCII strings. In this case, you should additionally write your software in C or something even more compact :)